# Unexpected keyword argument 'datatime' qiskit provider

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I'm trying to set datatime calling backend.properties qiskit.

this is my code :

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.providers.ibmq import *

provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q')
provider.backends(simulator=False)
backend = provider.get_backend(name)
prp = backend.properties(datatime=datatime).to_dict()
```

I'm getting this error : **TypeError: properties() got an unexpected keyword argument 'datatime'**.
If I use refresh = True and not datatime in propertis, the code works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword is `datetime`, not `datatime`.